# How to rename TestNG debug configuration in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

After I installeed TestNG plugin for Eclipse, I tried to configure the same. In the Run as well as Debug configuration, I get the name - Launch.label for a testng configuration. I am following a tutorial here - http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-installation that names the  configuration as TestNG. So I have two questions
1. Why is my configuration being labeled as Launch.label instead of TestNg
2. How can I get it changed.
Version -
TestNG - 5.14.1
Eclipse - 3.6

- Update
  Cedric has fixed the issue and put a patch at the location http://beust.com/eclipse/.
  I tested with the patch and the configuration naming and display is working fine now. i.e. I checked the two things.

  1. The TestNG Debug configuration is showing as TestNG instead of Launch.label
  2. I can create and rename a new configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the label in the left-side tree view of the "Debug Configurations" window, that's the name of a category of launch configurations, not your individual config; it's value comes from then plug-in itself and you can't change it. It sounds like the plugin has a bug where the actual name of the TestNG category isn't being set correctly.

Comment: Agreed, it looks like a bug, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Cedric. I also took the liberty of sending you an email about it yesterday.

Comment: Keeping this open till get some confirmation about this from Cedric.

Comment: I received your email, I should be able to fix this next week, feel free to email me again in a few days if you don't hear back from me.